# how we can use linux VM as shared hosted desktop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redhat

I want to provide Linux server as a RDS.
From thin client users have to access it(Thin clients have a ubuntu os). Is it possible in total Linux environment as like RDS in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use several protocols like RDP and VNC. Here are some posts related to this topic: [post1](https://askubuntu.com/q/592537/5927), [post2](https://askubuntu.com/q/4096/5927).

Comment: I use NoMachine for this. It runs across SSH and works flawlessly on Windows, Linux & OSX. `https://www.nomachine.com/`

Comment: no. I dont want to use any third party tool. My organisation allow only Linux in there environment.